# Cette phrase est-elle bonne grammaticalement ?

Tags: grammaire, sens

Bonjour ! Quelqu'un saurait-il me dire si cette phrase est bonne grammaticalement ?

> Me voila des plus heureux des hommes !

Merci !

Comment: Demandez si « des » est correct dans « des plus heureux », vous aurez une question et au moins une réponse.

Comment: Oui cette phrase est grammaticalement correcte, à mon avis, si elle signifie que tu fais partie du groupe "les plus heureux des hommes". Ce n'est probablement pas comme cela qu'on le dirait dans le language courant, mais c'est intéressant d'un point de vue littéraire, quoiqu'en disent ceux qui ont voté pour "put on hold" !!!